# Zend 1.x and Doctrine 2 - problem copying an object and its relations

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of the ->copy(true); method that existed in Doctrine 1.x, in my Doctrine 2 application, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know whats happened to ->copy()?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [`clone`](http://php.net/clone):

```
$new_one = clone $entity;
$manager->persist($new_one);
```

If you want to clone associations too, you may want to clone them in `__clone`:

```
function __clone() {
    $this->someAssoc = clone $this->someAssoc;
}
```

There are some restrictions, see http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Clone is a php function that isn't aware of any related entities. I need all related entities to be copied/cloned too.

Comment: The the other half of the answer :)

Comment: Thanks :) Would these associations need to be persisted individually? It seems that they aren't persisted if I only do it to the parent object.

Comment: It depends; use [cascade={"persist"}](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) on the association for doctrine to automatically persist the association

Comment: I'm already using cascade persist on its associated objects, but I'm having no luck - thanks for your help